Geo nodes - how do I create volume that's scaled down from the source mesh equally from all sides?
here's a basic illustration (Black is the mesh and red is the resulting volume): 
If I use mesh to volume node I will get volume that fills the entire mesh (1st variant from illustration).
I want it to be slightly scaled down equally from all sides. (2nd variant from illustration)
In a cube I could just scale the entire thing but when the shape becomes more complex scaling it won't scale it equally from all sides.

Hello, You need to displace the geometry along the face normals (eg inflate / deflate instead of scale)

Do you want an uniform displacement, i.e. the distance along the normal from a black face to the associated red face is the same, whatever the back face ?

For that, there is the Interior Band Width input of the Mesh to Volume node.

Could you provide a 2D (i.e. plane) example with small features and large faces, before and after scaling down ? It is to try and understand what do you mean by "Like scaling along the normals but not allow it to self intersect and stop scaling the parts that start to self intersect".

It won't scale it equally on all sides because with more complex objects you have to scale along the normals.
We don't have that option with a volume, so the object scale should be processed before the Mesh to Volume Node is implemented.
Voxel, Density, and Interior Bandwith will all change the volume shape afterwards.


In my example of a speaker cabinet, you can see that the volume is pretty close to the solid.
Transform/scale won't work to create this, and we can't even see the volume properly,  so:

Use a set of geo nodes to emulate Shrink/Fatten rather than scale or transform.  Realize any Instances before the volume interacts with the geometry.

Apply the shrink/fatten operation first to a solid object in the tree, because it is easier to preview it so that you can see the changes are accurate.

Use the Volume Info and Principled Volume nodes in the Shader Editor to see what is actually going on/ what is going to render, rather than depending on the selection outline.

Make the enclosing object cut away or transparent.


Group-

How it fit into the Speaker Example-

The relevant SE questions and answers are:
How to do a recursive Shrink/Fatten with Geometry Nodes?
Scaling along normals in Geometry Nodes

This approach technically works however finer details immediately self intersect when scaling down

@BenedictsForester: so the question : do you want to scale down (and displacement will not be the same for all faces) or to translate (and details of the order of the displacement will be lost) ?

I am not sure, I want to achieve basically this same thing just avoid intersection. Like scaling along the normals but not allow it to self intersect and stop scaling the parts that start to self intersect.
